# If $A$ is isomorphism and $T$ is compact, then $A+T$ is Fredholm?

Tags: operator-theory

I know, Brezis page 169
Given two Banach spaces $E$ and $F$, one says that $A \in \mathcal{L}(E, F)$ is a Fredholm operator (or a Noether operator)—one writes $A ∈ \Phi(E, F)$:

if $A$ is Fredholm then it has finite-dimensional kernel, finite-dimensional co-kernel, and closed range.

In the page 169 : If $A \in \Phi(E,F)$ is Fredholm and $T$ is compact, then $A+T$ is Fredholm.

Question: if $A$ is isomorphism and $T$ is compact, then $A+T$ is Fredholm?

Comment: Is your question a *lemma* to prove the theorem of p.169, or don't you just grasp why it is a *corollary* of that theorem? And in the first case, do you already know that $I+S$ is Fredholm when $I\in\mathcal L(E)$ and $S\in\mathcal K(E)$?

Comment: @AnneBauval I know $I+ S$ is Fredholm and $A+T$ is Fredholm , when $A$ is Fredholm. But when $A$ is isomorphism?

Comment: @AnneBauval $A + T$ is isomorphism when $A$ is and $T$ is compact and kernel is null and $ImA = F$?

Comment: No (e.g. $I+S$ is generally not an isomorphism). But an isomorphism is obviously Fredholm, this is why your question is a corollary of the theorem p.169.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you very much